# Spark SQL: error when using joins and subquery inside a UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a graph named `person_graph` that I'm trying to traverse.

This is `person_graph`:

```
start_node      end_node
Alice           Charles
Alice           David
Alice           Bob
Bob             George
Charles         Francis
Francis         Bob
Bob             George
George          Harrison
David           Edward
```

I have a function named `breadth_first_search` that takes a Spark dataframe containing a person and a "separation" as its input and performs one round of breadth first search using a join and a union.

Let's assume Alice is the start node (she has a separation of 0).  Here's an example of what the input dataframe `previously_traversed_nodes` would look like:

```
person     separation
Bob        1
David      1 
Alice      0
Charles    1
```

Here's the function:

```
def breadth_first_search(previously_traversed_nodes):
   
    sql_ query = '''
                SELECT person, separation

                FROM
                  previously_traversed_nodes

                UNION

                SELECT
                  person_graph.start_node AS node, ptn.distance + 1 AS separation
                  
                FROM
                  previously_traversed_nodes AS ptn

                JOIN
                  person_graph pg
                ON ptn.person = pg.start_node

                WHERE
                  person_graph.end_node NOT IN (
                                                 SELECT DISTINCT(person) FROM previously_traversed_nodes
                                             )

           '''

    result = spark.sql(sql_query)

    return result
```

When I register the function using the following:

```
spark.udf.register("BREADTH_FIRST_SEARCH", breadth_first_search, StringType())
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

At first, I thought the error was thrown because of the join.  So, I simplified the query to:

```
sql_query = 'SELECT person FROM previously_traversed_nodes'
```

I get the same error message.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the SparkSession / Context in a UDF.  In some circumstances they may appear to work (using local collections) but the second they are distributed to executors the SparkSession you have referenced will no longer exist.

You must change your code to use a join, or subquery (3.4 and above for useful correlated subqueries, 3.5 adds speed boosts), directly.